# Can't Log into Azure Virtual Machine created w/ Resource Manager

Tags: security, azure, virtual-machine, rdp

I just created a VM in Azure using the Resource Manager model. And I can't RDP to it.  The machine is running.  The error I receive is:

```
Your credentials did not work
```

I have tried the following user names:

```
myCompanyDomain\user
user
.\user
\user
NameOfVM\user
```

I have checked, double checked, and tripple checked the password.  I have read and followed all of the steps in this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections/#wincred

Still can't connect.  What am I missing?

Comment: Try resetting the remote access service as explained here. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections/  Scroll down about half-way to the ARM section.

Comment: @RickRainey, you linked to the same article to which I linked in my OP, and about which I said, "I have read and followed all of the steps in this article" !!

Comment: Doh!  Sorry about that.  I didn't pay close attention to the link you posted.  Try connecting using ".\<username>".  If that doesn't work you may want to contact support or just recreate the VM.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying various things, including deleting and recreating the VM.  I don't want to have to log a case with support, because that is usually a dead end road. But it might come to that.

Comment: I suspect this is a domain issue.  What domain should I be using?  If I try .\, then the RDP client changes the domain to SD12100.  (Not sure where that came from.)

Comment: It's the name of your computer (not the VM).  It's a habit I picked up long ago and have just always used it to change to the local user on VM when signing in.  Did you join the VM to a domain?  Even if you did you still can sign-in using the local user credentials you provided when creating the VM.

Comment: This seems to be some sort of bug in Azure related to my user.  When I create a VM, none of my co-workers or I can access it. When anyone else creates a VM (using the EXACT SAME steps) we can all access it.  I think this is going to end up being a support issue.  (deep breath)  Not what I needed right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the root of this problem is still a mystery.  If we figure it out, I'll post the solution. For whatever weird reason, when I create a VM, nobody (none of my co-workers nor I) can access it.  When anyone else creates a VM using the SAME STEPS, we can all access it.  But, we found a work around.  [This article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections/) helped, but didn't get us all the way there.

Here's the work around script:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName <Your Subscription Name>
```

Copy the Tenant Id returned above

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId <TenantId>

$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group Name> -Name <Your VM Name>

$cred = Get-Credential (this is the VM user credentials)

Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group Name> -VMName <Your VM Name> -Name VMAccessAgent -TypeHandlerVersion "2.0" -UserName $cred.UserName -Password $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password -Location <Location of VM>

Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group Name>  -VM $vm
```